# jobs shows nothing even with processes running in the background

Tags: command-line, scripts, background-process

I ran this script that runs several processes in parallel:

```
./train-eyecnn.sh 9 0.1 0 "key_relative_gaze" | tee "../tmp/9_0.1_0.txt" & 
./train-eyecnn.sh 9 0 0 "key_relative_gaze" | tee "../tmp/9_0_0.txt" &
./train-eyecnn.sh 9 0.1 1 "key_relative_gaze" | tee "../tmp/9_0.1_1.txt" &
./train-eyecnn.sh 9 0 1 "key_relative_gaze" | tee "../tmp/9_0_1.txt" &

wait
echo "All complete"
```

However, typing `jobs` shows nothing. I have checked that the monitor setting is set to `on`. How can I fix this?

```
haziq@blender:~$ set -o
allexport       off
braceexpand     on
emacs           on
errexit         off
errtrace        off
functrace       off
hashall         on
histexpand      on
history         on
ignoreeof       off
interactive-comments    on
keyword         off
monitor         on
noclobber       off
noexec          off
noglob          off
nolog           off
notify          off
nounset         off
onecmd          off
physical        off
pipefail        off
posix           off
privileged      off
verbose         off
vi              off
xtrace          off
```

Here are my 4 processes through `nvidia-smi`:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 418.67       Driver Version: 418.67       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce RTX 208...  On   | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 27%   32C    P8    20W / 250W |     11MiB / 10986MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
|   1  TITAN V JHH Spe...  On   | 00000000:02:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| 36%   53C    P2    44W / 250W |   4960MiB / 32478MiB |      0%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    1     16399      C   ...ample_global_optical_flow_test_sequence   309MiB |
|    1     27324      C   python                                      1155MiB |
|    1     27325      C   python                                      1163MiB |
|    1     27326      C   python                                      1165MiB |
|    1     27327      C   python                                      1157MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: AFAIK when you use `&` in a *script*, you're putting processes into the background of the script's shell, rather than that of your current interactive shell.

Comment: @steeldriver sorry but i am very new to this. Do you mean its not possible to terminate the process then?

Comment: You can terminate them using their PID rather than their job number - either directly, like `kill 27324`, or indirectly using `pkill` for example